# C++ SOCI query into vector of custom Object

Tags: c++, soci

Currently I'm writing a C++ application where I have to connect to a SQLite database. I search for a library and found SOCI and I have to say: I love it. The stream syntax and the mapping is so awesome. But I have one problem with it:

I have an Event class and I've written the parser functions for it:

```
template<> struct type_conversion<Event>
{
    typedef values base_type;

    static void from_base(const values& v, indicator /* ind */, Event& event)
    {
        event.m_id = v.get<std::string>("id");
        event.m_title = v.get<std::string>("Title");
        event.m_description = v.get<std::string>("Description");
        event.m_date = v.get<std::tm>("Date");
    }

    static void to_base(const Event& event, values& v, indicator& ind)
    {
        v.set("id", event.m_id);
        v.set("Title", event.m_title);
        v.set("Description", event.m_description);
        v.set("Date", event.m_date);

        ind = i_ok;
    }
};
```

This works great for queries like this:

```
sql << "SELECT * FROM Event WHERE id=5", into(event);
```

I would like to select a bulk of Events into a `std::vector<Event*>` but if I try this with:

```
std::vector<Event*> events;
sql << "SELECT * FROM Event", into(events)
```

But with this I get following compiler error:

```
No known convertation from
soci::details::conversion_into_type<std::vector<Event>> into
soci::details::into_type_base
```

Isn't that possible with SOCI or am I missing something? I also found OTL as library. Is that maybe a good alternative? As I said I like the SOCI way. Is something like this also possible with OTL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOCI does not support combination of ORM with bulk operations. See the mailing list thread: [ORM with std::vector not supported?](https://sourceforge.net/p/soci/mailman/message/19607893/).

Instead, you can use rowset and iterator-based access:

```
rowset<Event> rs = (sql.prepare << "SELECT * FROM Event");
for (auto it = rs.cbegin(); it != rs.cend(); ++it)
{
   // access event
}
```

AFAIR, it still should be supported.

Comment: Great thank you for this! I have two more questions: Does SOCI cache objects in the background if I execute the same query again? And what is the correct way to declare the `rowset` as friend so I can make the default constructor private? I tried `friend class soci::rowset<Event>` but this does not work.

Comment: SOCI does not cache anything between issuing separate queries. Type used to specialise rowset must be default constructible.

Comment: It should be default constructable if the rowset is a friend of my class and the constructor is private or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: `Event` can not have private constructor. That is requirement of `rowset` (and internal `rowset_impl` class). Take a look into the SOCI code and you will see why (ie. `new T()`). You can always modify SOCI code according to your needs.

Comment: Any idea to insert the std::vector of custom types ?

Comment: @srilakshmikanthanp you can follow this discussion here: [ORM: the query result rowset becomes invalid after a for loop · Issue #1064 · SOCI/soci](https://github.com/SOCI/soci/issues/1064), I think it is the correct way to construct a vector of custom types.