# How to bulk insert with std::vector of custom object in soci?

Tags: c++, orm, soci

I have [seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260993/c-soci-query-into-vector-of-custom-object) but how to insert a set of custom objects of std::vector into a database using the soci database library

For example, take the c++ class representing a table,

```
struct one_min_equity {
  int64_t id;
  std::string timestamp;
  double open;
  double high;
  double low;
  double close;
  int64_t volume;
  int64_t open_interest;
  std::string symbol;
  double ltq;
};
```

Corresponding type conversion,

```
// Type conversion for the database
namespace soci {

/**
 * @brief type_conversion for one_min_equity
 */
template <>
struct type_conversion<one_min_equity> {
  typedef values base_type;

  // convert from database type to your custom type
  static void from_base(const values &v, indicator, one_min_equity &p) {
    p.id = v.get<int64_t>("id");
    p.timestamp = v.get<std::string>("timestamp");
    p.open = v.get<double>("open");
    p.high = v.get<double>("high");
    p.low = v.get<double>("low");
    p.close = v.get<double>("close");
    p.volume = v.get<int64_t>("volume");
    p.open_interest = v.get<int64_t>("open_interest");
    p.symbol = v.get<std::string>("symbol");
    p.ltq = v.get<double>("ltq");
  }

  // convert from your custom type to database type
  static void to_base(const one_min_equity &p, values &v, indicator &ind) {
    v.set("id", p.id);
    v.set("timestamp", p.timestamp);
    v.set("open", p.open);
    v.set("high", p.high);
    v.set("low", p.low);
    v.set("close", p.close);
    v.set("volume", p.volume);
    v.set("open_interest", p.open_interest);
    v.set("symbol", p.symbol);
    v.set("ltq", p.ltq);
    ind = i_ok;
  }
};
}
```

This is compiling fine,

```
void push_one_min_equity_data(const models::one_min_equity &rows) {
  // Get the database session from the database module
  auto &session = database::get_session();

  // Prepare the statement
  soci::statement stmt = (session.prepare << R"(
    INSERT INTO one_min_equity (
      timestamp,
      open,
      high,
      low,
      close,
      volume,
      open_interest,
      symbol,
      ltq
    ) VALUES (
      :timestamp,
      :open,
      :high,
      :low,
      :close,
      :volume,
      :open_interest,
      :symbol,
      :ltq
    )
 )", soci::use(rows));

  // Execute the statement
  stmt.execute(true);
}
```

But if I change the rows into vector of rows

```
void push_one_min_equity_data(const std::vector<models::one_min_equity> &rows)
```

It doesn't work How to accomplish the bulk insert. I can't insert for each object of vector because it give poor performance. it isn't ?

Comment: Since you are worried by efficiency the first change you should make is to pass your parameters by const reference. `void push_one_min_equity_data(const models::one_min_equity& rows)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Any solution for bulk insert :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this library.

Comment: Do you know any alternative open-source library to interact postgress with C++ with support for these operations? As far as I searched this is a good one I found